# Is it possible to determine if ruby code block is executed under http server or as standalone script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am writing a ruby gem and I want to be able to differentiate if gem is being used under http server (i.e invoked as a part of rails framework) or If ruby gem is is invoked from standalone script say like ruby test_script.rb.

I know I could check certain ENV variables such as 'REMOTE_ADDR' , 'HTTP_REFERER' to decide if it originated from web application or standalone script.  But obviously it wont be correct all the time so was just wondering if there is any better way to check if ruby code block is being executed under http server.

thanks

Comment: `UNDER_RAILS = Kernel.const_defined? 'Rails'`

Comment: yes , I could do that but that is specific to rails only what about other frameworks ?  because other framework definitely wont use this variable so was looking for more generic solution that could work for most frameworks so dont have to update codebase every time there is new framework.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a ruby script is being run on the command line (or not) by checking if the current file name matches the name of the file that is being executed.

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  # ruby gem_name.rb
  puts "On the command line"
else
  # require 'gem_name'
  puts "Gem has been required"
end
```

Comment: unfortunatly it won't do what i want. If I use __FILE__ inside ruby gem file it will only give me file name which i already know.  It wont tell anything if its running under http server or not.